# Find a string in a input file - C++

Tags: c++

I need to find a string (link name) input by the user in a text file.
How can approach a solution in c++? Do I have to store the file context in structs in order to read the data later? Or can I just open and read the file whenever i want to look for info?
Thank you!

**Input file sample**

```
111.176.4.191 www.yahoo.com 01/04/2013
111.176.4.191 www.yahoo.com 01/09/2013
192.168.1.101 www.yahoo.com 01/04/2013
111.176.4.191 www.yahoo.com 01/12/2013
192.168.1.101 www.espn.com 01/05/2013
```

**C++ code**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


//gobal variables, procedures

void fileinfo1(string);

char IP_Address [12];

char Link_Name [50];

char Date_Accessed [8];

string filename;

int menu;


int main()
{
    // the user will input the file name here
    cout << "Enter filename> ";

    getline( cin, filename );

    fstream file( filename.c_str() );

    if (!file)

    {

        cout << "Invalid file.\n";


        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // the program will display the file context
    else
    {
        string line;
        int count = 10;
        while ((count > 0) && getline( file, line ))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
            count--;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    // The user will be able to choose to see info about all entries or a particular one

    cout << "Please select a menu option:";
    cout << "1)Link Information in date range";
    cout << "2)Information about all links";
    cout << "3)Quit the program";
    cin >> menu;

    switch (menu) {

    // see info about a particular link
    case 1: fileinfo1(filename);
        break;

    case 2:
        break;

    case 3:
        break;

    default: cout << "Please a choose a number between 1 and 3";
        break;

    }

    // the file is passed to this function
    void fileinfo1(string filename) {

        //the user will input a link e.g www.espn.com
        cout << "What is the link name? ";

        cin >> Link_Name;

        // and also input date range (start-end)
        cout << "What is the starting date? " ;

        cin >> Date_Accessed;

        cout << "What is the ending date? " ;

        cin >> Date_Accessed;

        // Now, here's where I'm having trouble

        // I need to find the wwww.espn.com in my file based on the range date , so that i will be able to increment the number of hits

        unsigned int curLine = 0;
        while (getline(filename, line)) { // I changed this, see below
            curLine++;
            if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos) {
                cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what's wrong with the code you posted? seems like a valid way of achieving the result.

Comment: The last lines of code aren't getting the correct data from the file. If I input www.espn.com , it should be able to find cuz it exists on the file. But that's not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Part of the code shouldnt be written into your main() function.

```
// the file is passed to this function
void fileinfo1(string filename) {

    //the user will input a link e.g www.espn.com
    cout << "What is the link name? ";

    cin >> Link_Name;

    // and also input date range (start-end)
    cout << "What is the starting date? " ;

    cin >> Date_Accessed;

    cout << "What is the ending date? " ;

    cin >> Date_Accessed;

    // Now, here's where I'm having trouble

    // I need to find the wwww.espn.com in my file based on the range date , so that i will be able to increment the number of hits

    unsigned int curLine = 0;
    while (getline(filename, line)) { // I changed this, see below
        curLine++;
        if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos) {
            cout << "found: " << search << "line: " << curLine << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

and you are using way to many global variables which are really not necessary. And you dident declare the variables line and search. This shoudnt even compile.

Comment: Yeah, it was a silly mistake. I put the function out of the main. It's all good now. Just have to finish reading through the file and find the data that I need

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a quick and dirty solution or an elegant one?

For an elegant solution, I would:

- Ditch the globals.
- Read the entire file into memory before parsing it.
- Generate an internal database for your data.
- Write a few query functions that return a subset of your data.

For your particular case, you could use a std::multimap < LinkName, DateAndIP > to find all data relating to the link. DateAndIP could be a typedef to std::multimap < Date, IP > . If you've never used multimap, this will be a good learning experience. Write your compare functions and use the find member function to return only what you're looking for.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I'll look into std::multimap. Thanks.